# Open a local pdf file from Delphi Firemonkey Code for Android App

Tags: delphi, pdf, document, firemonkey

NOTE: Delphi XE8, Firemonkey  App for Android 4.4.2

I am trying to open a pdf document from Android App made with Firemonkey and only open the Adobe Acrobat, but the file doesn't, then I have found online in several webpages and I have tried every one of them, but no one works.

The error message is

> Adobe can't find the document to open

But the document is in a public folder, and I have moved it for differents folder and nothing happend.

I have opened images from other folders without problem, I don't understand.

Can anybody give me a solution please?.

```
procedure TForm1.bttnAbrirClick(Sender: TObject);
var
NombreFichero,
RutaRaiz,
Ruta_Fichero,
Ruta_Fichero2    : String;

begin

// NombreFichero     := 'Doc1.pdf';

//  RutaRaiz          := 'File:///storage/emulated/0/TabletBigger/Images/Articulos';
//   RutaRaiz          := '/storage/emulated/0/TabletBigger/Images/Articulos';
// RutaRaiz          := '/storage/sdcard0/TabletBigger/Images/Articulos';         // en mi tablet
//  Ruta_Fichero      := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(RutaRaiz, NombreFichero);
//  Ruta_Fichero      := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDownloadsPath, NombreFichero);
// Ruta_Fichero      := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetSharedDownloadsPath, RutaRaiz);

  NombreFichero      := 'Introduccion.pdf';
  Ruta_Fichero2      := '/storage/emulated/0/TabletBigger/Images/Articulos/Introduccion.pdf';
  Ruta_Fichero       := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetPublicPath, NombreFichero);

  showtext.Text :=  Ruta_Fichero;

  open(Ruta_Fichero);

   // Ruta_Fichero :=  StringReplace(StringReplace( Ruta_Fichero, '\', '\\', [rfReplaceAll]), '"', '\"', [rfReplaceAll]) + '"';
   //_system(PAnsiChar('Open ' + AnsiString(Ruta_Fichero)))

end;


procedure TForm1.Open(Ruta_Fichero : String);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
begin

if FileExists(Ruta_Fichero) then
begin
    Intent := TJIntent.Create;
    Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
    Intent.setDataAndType(StrToJURI(Ruta_Fichero), StringToJString('application/pdf'));
    Intent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    try
      SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
    Except

    end;

end
else
  _MessageDlg('El fichero no existe', mssInf);

end;
```

Comment: ¡Solve it ! the good answer I founded at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699574/delphi-open-pdf-from-ios-android-local-storage?rq=1        by  afzalali15.

Answer (score 1):

¡Solve it !

the good answer I founded at: [Delphi open PDF from ios/Android local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699574/delphi-open-pdf-from-ios-android-local-storage?rq=1)

by  afzalali15.

I'll try to Upload the whole code  .

Thanks anyway.